# Elasticsearch search template resulting in "Improperly closed variable" when trying to render

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following template I am trying to use on Elasticsearch 6.6.2:

```
{
{{#hasSpecialIDFilters}}
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "mySpecialID": [{{#join}}mySpecialIDFilters{{/join}}]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
{{/hasSpecialIDFilters}}
    "sort": [
        {
            "mySortingField": "desc"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a Java application that transforms this template to be part of a RESTful request body and sends it to my cluster.  I should note that I have other templates that run through this system with no issue.  The resulting request is:

```
{
    "script": {
        "lang": "mustache",
        "source":"{{{#hasSpecialIDFilters}}\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"terms\":{\"mySpecialID\":[{{#join}}mySpecialIDFilters{{/join}}]}}]}},{{/hasSpecialIDFilters}}\"sort\":[{\"mySortingField\":\"desc\"}]}"    }
}
```

When I try to render the template:

```
POST _render/template/my-special-template
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "general_script_exception",
                "reason": "Failed to compile stored script [my-special-template] using lang [mustache]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "general_script_exception",
        "reason": "Failed to compile stored script [my-special-template] using lang [mustache]",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "mustache_exception",
            "reason": "Improperly closed variable in query-template:1"
        }
    },
    "status": 500
}
```

If I remove the `{{#hasSpecialIDFilters}}` and `{{/hasSpecialIDFilters}}` lines, the template renders fine, but I use that value as a boolean to dictate whether I should include the terms array bool query within.  I am not sure why this is an issue, since everything looks syntactically correct.

A workaround for me would be to just maintain two separate templates, one requiring the `mySpecialIDFilters` array, and one without it, with my calling code dictating which one to call, but I'd rather have it within one template.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be the issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `join` function, you need to use the `toJson` function and it will work:

```
{
{{#hasSpecialIDFilters}}
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "mySpecialID": {{#toJson}}mySpecialIDFilters{{/toJson}}
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
{{/hasSpecialIDFilters}}
    "sort": [
        {
            "mySortingField": "desc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then you can invoke your template like this and it will work:

```
POST _render/template/my-special-template
{
  "params": {
    "hasSpecialIDFilters": true,
    "mySpecialIDFilters": [1,2]
  }
}
```